# Android: "Can not resolve method 'x()'" when overriding superclass methods

Tags: java, android, inheritance, widget

I am trying to override a few methods from a class called AbsSeekBar. However, Android Studio underlines super.methodname() with the message mentioned in the title and @Override with 'Method does not override method from it's superclass', even though the method is right there. Code example:

Subclass:

```
import android.widget.AbsSeekBar;

public class VerticalSeekBar extends AbsSeekBar {

    // Constructors, work fine
    ...

    @Override
    void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser, int progress) {
         super.onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser, progress);

        if (mOnSeekBarChangeListener != null) {
            mOnSeekBarChangeListener.onProgressChanged(this, progress, fromUser);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Code of the superclass:

```
public abstract class AbsSeekBar extends ProgressBar {

    // Some methods
    ...

    @Override
    void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser, int progress) {
        super.onProgressRefresh(scale, fromUser, progress);

        final Drawable thumb = mThumb;
        if (thumb != null) {
        setThumbPos(getWidth(), thumb, scale, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        // Since we draw translated, the drawable's bounds that it signals
        // for invalidation won't be the actual bounds we want invalidated,
        // so just invalidate this whole view.
        invalidate();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Has the issue resolved?

Comment: @SrikarReddy Unfortunately not. Are you having the same problem?

Comment: Yes, having the same problem with onProgressRefresh. Not sure why it is happening and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your AbsSeekBar method onProgressRefresh is marked @Override.  Does ProgressBar define a method onProgressRefresh(float, boolean, int)?

Comment: Yes, it does:
`void onProgressRefresh(float scale, boolean fromUser, int progress) {

        if (AccessibilityManager.getInstance(mContext).isEnabled()) {

            scheduleAccessibilityEventSender();

        }

    }`